# How to display the text in the xpath without element name

Tags: xml, xpath

The sample xml is:

```
<Parents>
  <Parent>
    <Children>
      <child>child2_Parent_1</child>
      <child>child4_Parent_1</child>
      <child>child1_Parent_1</child>
      <child>child3_Parent_1</child>
    </Children>
    <Children>
      <child>child1_parent2</child>
      <child>child2_parent2</child>
      <child>child4_parent2</child>
      <child>child3_parent2</child>
    </Children>
  </Parent>
</parents>
```

I just want to select all child out,
the select express is:

```
/parents/parent/children/child
```

the result is:

```
Element='<child>child2_Parent_1</child>'
Element='<child>child4_Parent_1</child>'
Element='<child>child1_Parent_1</child>'
Element='<child>child3_Parent_1</child>'
Element='<child>child1_parent2</child>'
Element='<child>child2_parent2</child>'
Element='<child>child4_parent2</child>'
Element='<child>child3_parent2</child>'
```

But I just wanna text without the elemnet/node name.

```
child2_Parent_1
child4_Parent_1
...
```

Comment: I assume `Parents` versus `parents` etc is just a typo in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `text()` node function:

```
/Parents/Parent/Children/child/text()
```

Comment: Hi, The result shows “text = ‘...’”.  But how can obtain pure text without “text=“

Comment: That may be something to do with the tool you are using. See http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/914d9b99ce710e985640d893afd61385 for an working example.

Answer (score 0):

XPath selects nodes, it doesn't display the result. If you want to display these nodes differently, you don't have to change how you select them, you only have to change how you display them. You haven't told us what you do to execute the XPath expression and display its result, but this is what you need to change.

You can change the expression to add `/text()`, which may give a result closer to what you are wanting, but the display output still depends on how you use the results of the XPath evaluation, and not on the XPath evaluation itself.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the contains(text) method. See below..

```
Parents//Children/child[contains(text(),'child')]
```

I use the relative path with // after Parents. This will grep all the same patterns in your xml. The trick here is I assume that each of the text has or contains 'child' string/text. If it is, then you will get the result that you want.

Comment: This isn't going to change which elements are selected and therefore it isn't going to change how they are displayed. And talk of "grep" and "patterns" here is very loose language which can only serve to confuse the OP even further.